# How to move individual layers using onion skin when rotoscoping with video layers in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I am using a video layer to animate frame-by-frame over a video. Because the video shifts over a little, the rotoscope is not a perfect loop, so I would like to move the shifting frames over one-by-one. I have turned on onion skins to do this, however, when I use the move tool to move my selected contents the contents of the frame are selected but the onion skin disappears, so I can't see the past or next frame so that I know where to move it to.

[image: Frame with onion skin on before selecting and moving]

[image: Frame after selecting -- onion skins disappear! (when I go to onion skin settings they still are not visible)]

Comment: Just tried this. It seems that the onion skin is disabled while you drag with the mouse, but not if you just nudge the layer with the keyboard arrows. Could that be a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is always using the the transformation tool to move the video layer without making the onion skin bug out, but then you'd always have to press enter.

Personally is much better using either Clip Paint Studio or Krita, CSP also supports direct import of Ps brushes and retains their mechanics so it's great if you want to stick with your brushes.